# Bytecode injection countermeasures in jar files

Tags: java, security, bytecode

I have a jnlp application that loads and executes a jar  file ( client ) on a users computer. The user uses this jar to communicate with a server that provides a services. I've seen users using javassit and javasnoop to alter the functionality of the client. Is there any way I can remotelly detect changes created by the previously mentionted utilities ? For example, can I checksum the classes locally and send the result to the server ( who knows the correct checksum of each class ) ?

Comment: They could just instrument your checks as well. Therefore: No.

Comment: If you make your client bullet-proof people start hacking the communication between the client and the server. Or just use an alternative client…

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in general to prevent the client from running any code they wish to. The security of your system should never rely on assuming that clients are running specific code or are not aware of specific information contained in the jars you send them.

Furthermore, attempts to impose DRM tend to cause problems for legitimate users and alienate your customers while doing little to prevent people who actually do want to hack the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example create a check sum of your java file and make your application to calculate the checksum at runtime and send it for verification to server. The simplest checksum is a hash code of whole jar.

The only question is why? And who is the super user that takes your jar and performs instrumentation on it? And why is he doing this? And even if he has reasons, who cares? If you are afraid that somebody is going to hack your server make *it* secure enough and do not care about client (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

You can open a classfile named `p1.p2.ClName` with Classloader.getResourceAsStream(`"/p1/p2/ClName.class"`), read it, and compute its checksum.

But, as user can change the functionality, he can also remove that checksum checking.